# How to get Instagram access_token via React.js

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I have problem with user authentication with Instagram OAuth2.0 in React.js.

What is the flow of authentication? I know how to send request with client_id and client_secret with node.js, but what if user need to set login/password? How to redirect user to Instagram page from React.js? How to recieve access_token?

Comment: You have to redirect user by instagram authorization URL https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: I found solution. Fastest way is to use Passport.js with Instagram OAuth npm passport-instagram